# Batch script for making new dirs, named as part of filename and move the files in

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

For example:
I have alot of files, named like this in one directory:

```
stuff1.jpg
stuff1 (1).jpg
stuff1 (2).jpg
stuff2.jpg
stuff2 (1).jpg
stuff2 (2).jpg
...and etc.
```

I want the batch script to move `stuff1*` files to subfolder, named `stuff1`; `stuff2*` files to subfolder, named `stuff2` and etc.

I found this batch script:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b') do (
if not "%%~fa"=="%~f0" (
md "%%~na" 2>nul
if exist "%%a" move "%%~na.*" "%%~na"
)
)
```

but it makes separate dirs for the `stuff1 (1).jpg` and `stuff1 (2).jpg` files

**Edit:** `stuff1` and `stuff2` are just examples, they can be any one-word string. And sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for "one-word string" you mean "a string before the first dot or space", then the Batch file below do that. If your "one-word string" may be separated by other characters, then include them in the `"delims=...` part of the FOR command (leaving the space in last place).

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.*) do (
   for /F "delims=. " %%b in ("%%a") do (
      if not exist "%%b\" md "%%b"
      if exist "%%a" move "%%b*.*" "%%b"
   )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pure batch:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "startfolder=test"

CD /d %startfolder%
FOR %%a IN (*.jpg) DO (
    FOR /f "delims=. " %%b IN ("%%~a") DO (
        ECHO MD "%%~b" 2>nul
        ECHO MOVE "%%~a" "%%~b"
    )
)
```

---

Example with [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "startfolder=test"

CD /d %startfolder%
FOR %%a IN (*.jpg) DO (
    FOR /f %%b IN ('echo %%~a^|sed -r "s/(\w+).*/\1/"') DO (
        ECHO MD "%%~b" 2>nul
        ECHO MOVE "%%~a" "%%~b"
    )
)
```

.. output:

```
>dir /b test
stuff1 (1).jpg
stuff1.jpg
stuff10 (1).jpg
stuff10.jpg
stuff2 (1).jpg
stuff2.jpg
stuff20 (1).jpg
stuff20.jpg
>script
MD "stuff1"
MOVE "stuff1 (1).jpg" "stuff1"
MD "stuff1"
MOVE "stuff1.jpg" "stuff1"
MD "stuff10"
MOVE "stuff10 (1).jpg" "stuff10"
MD "stuff10"
MOVE "stuff10.jpg" "stuff10"
MD "stuff2"
MOVE "stuff2 (1).jpg" "stuff2"
MD "stuff2"
MOVE "stuff2.jpg" "stuff2"
MD "stuff20"
MOVE "stuff20 (1).jpg" "stuff20"
MD "stuff20"
MOVE "stuff20.jpg" "stuff20"
```

Please look at your output and remove `echo` before `MD` and `Move`,  if it looks good.

Comment: Thank you, but probably i have not explained well.
Stuff1 and Stuff2 are just examples, they can be any one-word string. And sorry for the bad english

Comment: If you need a safe solution for a one word string file name look at my `sed`  example. Tis works so.